# After reading a csv using header/skiprows argument values become NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I'm an trying to open a csv file with the header spanning multiple rows. To avoid dealing with MultiIndex I am using the header argument to skip some lines, but all values become NaNs.

An example which reproduces the error:

```
,,
x,a,c
y,b,d
labels,l1,l2
2016-01-01,1,6
2016-01-02,2.0,7.0
2016-01-03,3.0,8
```

test.csv

```
t = pandas.read_csv('test.csv',skiprows=3, header=[0], index_col=[0]
```

or

```
t = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', header=[3], index_col=[0] )
```

produce the same output

```
labels       l1   l2
2016-01-01  NaN  NaN
2016-01-02  NaN  NaN
2016-01-03  NaN  NaN

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

When I'm using all 3 header rows

```
t = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', header=[1,2,3], index_col=[0] )
```

it works and I can access the data.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

ps: I'm now using the MultiIndex, I had a problem where I got a KeyError because i forgot one argument (the header has 8 rows ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this:

```
my_file = 'test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(my_file, sep=',', names=['labels', 'l1', 'l2'], skiprows=4, header=None)
```

Forget about the first 4 rows entirely and specify the headers yourself.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
In [20]: pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=3)
Out[20]:
       labels   l1   l2
0  2016-01-01  1.0  6.0
1  2016-01-02  2.0  7.0
2  2016-01-03  3.0  8.0
```